# regarding a code segment that uses lambda

Tags: python, pandas

There is a code segment aiming to realize the following effect. The code segment is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

for layer in model.layers:
    if layer.name in ['fc1', 'fc2', 'logit']:
       continue
   layer.trainable = False

df = pd.DataFrame(([layer.name, layer.trainable] for layer in model.layers), columns=['layer', 'trainable'])
df.style.applymap(lambda trainable: f'background-color: {"yellow" if trainable else "red"}', subset=['trainable'])
```

However, the code of `df.style.applymap(lambda trainable: f'background-color: {"yellow" if trainable else "red"}', subset=['trainable'])` causes the error message of

```
  SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What might be wrong for this part? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: You're trying to use f-string syntax, which was introduced in Python 3.6. Are you actually running Python 3.6?

Comment: If you're not on Py3.6 that lambda should read `lambda trainable: 'background-color: {0}'.format('"yellow"' if trainable else '"red"')`

Comment: (though honestly f-strings are enough reason to upgrade to Py3.6 on their own <3)

Comment: Adam, thanks a lot for the reply. It works.